# Obtain WSO2 API Manager synapse resource uri-template from MessageContext

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apache-synapse

Is there any way to get resource uri-template value from MessageContext to be used in custom Handler?

For example, if the api synapse config is

```
...
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
         name="something"
         context="something"
         version="something"
         version-type="context">
       <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/?test={test2}" faultSequence="fault">
...
```

how can i get the '`/?test={test2}`' string into my custom handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use following inside your handler

```
String resourceString = (String) synCtx.getProperty("API_ELECTED_RESOURCE");
```

where synCtx is the MessageContext